# Cast list item to generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics

I have a following interface:

```
interface IStorage
{ }
```

and then I have a class that derives from this interface (which is generic) with, for example, with a property Get

```
public class ManagingModel<T> : IStorage
{
    public Func<T> Get { get; set; }
}
```

To have a list of those objects, I'm using the `List<IStorage>`

The question is, how do I cast the item from the List to `ManagingModel<>` to access this property?

Comment: You should provide the name of property

Comment: How do you know what type you need? What is the calling code going to do with the `Func<T>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, user of my code will create the instance of `ManagingModel<T>`, and using the `Get` func i'll get some objects (it doesn't matter, for what purpose)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilev - That's got nothing to do with getting the `ManagingModel<T>` from the `List<IStorage>`. What will the calling code need to do with the `Func<T>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity my code will just check if it is not null, then call it and pass the result to View (asp.net mvc).

Comment: @KonstantinVasilev - Then it can do it as an `Func<object>` and doesn't need a `Func<T>` at all?

Comment: @Enigmativity actually there're other properties like `Delete<T>`, `Add<T>` and I wanted to restrict them to specific type

Comment: @KonstantinVasilev - Then you need to ask a better question. We can't hope to give you the answer you need if you don't ask the right question.

Comment: @Enigmativity although I'll use your solution, it is not the answer to my initial question

Answer (score 2):

For example you can access list element by index. Example:

```
    var managingString = new ManagingModel<string>();
    var managingInt = new ManagingModel<int>();
    var managingDouble = new ManagingModel<double>();

    var list = new List<IStorage>();

    list.Add(managingString);
    list.Add(managingInt);
    list.Add(managingDouble);
```

Trying to cast "as" given model via index:

```
    var backToManagingModel = list[1] as ManagingModel<int>;

    if (backToManagingModel != null)
    {
        var get = backToManagingModel.Get;
    }
```

If backToManagingModel is null after casting, then it's being casted to wrong type, otherwise casting is sucessful and you can get your property.

Edit: What about not using generics at all, but simply use object?

```
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return "xyz";
    }

    public interface IStorage
    {
        Func<object> Get { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManagingModel : IStorage
    {
        public Func<object> Get { get; set; }
    }
```

You won't need to check all the types, just call `list[index].Get`

```
        var managingString = new ManagingModel
        {
            Get = new Func<string>(GetString)
        };

        var list = new List<IStorage>();

        list.Add(managingString);

        var get = list[1].Get;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but there could be a lot of types (I cannot control which they will be). So I cannot just check for all possible variants.

Comment: After update: yes, I considered this approach, but I would like to use the flexibility of generic types in compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of the `Func<T>` is going to a view then you probably can extend `IStorage` to do it as a `Func<object>`.

Try this:

```
interface IStorage
{
    Func<object> Get { get; }
}

public class ManagingModel<T> : IStorage
{
    public Func<T> Get { get; set; }

    Func<object> IStorage.Get
    {
        get
        {
            return () => this.Get();
        }
    }
}
```